# How do I get the second integer in a Ruby string with to_i?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I need to convert some strings, and pull out the two first integers e.g:

> unkowntext60moreunknowntext25something

To:

```
@width = 60
@height = 25
```

If I do `string.to_i`, I get the first integer:, 60. I can't figure out how I get the second integer, 25. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about something like:

```
text = "unkowntext60moreunknowntext25something"
@width, @height = text.scan(/\d+/).map { |n| n.to_i }  #=> 60, 25
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@width, @height = "unkowntext60moreunknowntext25something".scan(/[0-9]+/)
```

Comment: this returns strings, not integers

Comment: That's true, you can easily cast them to int using to_i but something it's just fine to keep them as string (if the receiver doesn't need to get integers or it casts them again to string. this is a common case if you use @width and @height in a Rals helper).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression like `(\d+)` to capture all numbers in the string and then iterate the capture groups converting each one to an integer.

**Edit**: I don't know Ruby so I've wiki'd this answer in hopes that a Rubyist would flesh out a code example.